# Google play is not listing the published application

Tags: google-play

I have published my app in google play before a week still it is not listing in the search and I have tried to find my app using package name, giving the app name in double-quotes no luck with the things. But i was able to identify my app from our other app page like more from the company section. What is the solution to overcome this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: need link to publisher and package name